# Как скопировать результат в буфер

Tags: javascript, html

При отмечении чекбоксов внизу появляется результат. Как при нажатии на button "Copy" скопировать  только полученный  результат в буфер?

```js
// sum

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.sum_value input').click(function () {
      var sum = 0;
      $('.sum_value input').each(function () {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).parent().find('span').text().replace(/[^0-9.,]/gim, ''));
         }

      });
      sum = sum.toLocaleString() + '';
      sum = sum.replace(',', '.');
      $('.options_sum span').html(sum);
   });
});

// value

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.sum_value input').click(function () {
      $('#options_value').html('');
      $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
         $('#options_value').append($(this).val() + '<br>');
      });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js_script.js" defer></script>
  
<div class="grid_css">
    <div class="column_1">
      <ul id="accordion">
        <li>
          <div class="line_All_green">

            <div class="sum_value">

              <div id="1" class="table-td">
                <input type="checkbox" value="11111" id="1_1"><span>A 1</span>
              </div>
              <div id="2" class="table-td">
                <input type="checkbox" value="22222" id="2_2"><span>B 2</span>
              </div>
              <div id="3" class="table-td">
                <input type="checkbox" value="33333" id="3_3"><span>C 3</span>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="column_2">
      <div class="options_sum" id="options_sum">Sum: <span></span></div>Value:
      <div class="options_value" id="options_value">
        <p id="options_value" class="options_value"></p>
      </div>
      <button> Copy </button>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого достаточно одной строки `navigator.clipboard.writeText('some string')` - [описание](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sum_value input').click(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.sum_value input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).parent().find('span').text().replace(/[^0-9.,]/gim, ''));
      }

    });
    sum = sum.toLocaleString() + '';
    sum = sum.replace(',', '.');
    $('.options_sum span').html(sum);
  });
});

// value

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sum_value input').click(function() {
    $('#options_value').html('');
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      $('#options_value').append($(this).val() + '<br>');
    });
  });

  $('button').on('click', () => {
    let text = $('#options_value').html();
    text = text.replaceAll('<br>', "\n");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid_css">
  <div class="column_1">
    <ul id="accordion">
      <li>
        <div class="line_All_green">

          <div class="sum_value">

            <div id="1" class="table-td">
              <input type="checkbox" value="11111" id="1_1"><span>A 1</span>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="table-td">
              <input type="checkbox" value="22222" id="2_2"><span>B 2</span>
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="table-td">
              <input type="checkbox" value="33333" id="3_3"><span>C 3</span>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="column_2">
    <div class="options_sum" id="options_sum">Sum: <span></span></div>Value:
    <div class="options_value" id="options_value">
      <p id="options_value" class="options_value"></p>
    </div>
    <button> Copy </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Однко после вставки они выстраиваются в линию. Как вывести построчно?

Comment: @DuKr8 очевидно же - заменить метод text() на html()

Comment: после замены такой результат
22222<br>33333<br>

Comment: @DuKr8 дописал код

Comment: Спасибо. То что надо и код понятен, разобрался.